# Action bar drop down and view pager not working independently

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, android-viewpager, android-spinner

I want to use view pager and action bar drop down(spinner). But i am facing the problem that the view pager and drop down are not working independently. 
My same question is here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22496578/using-acion-bar-drop-down-with-view-pager
Please can you suggest me the way so that i can use both view pager as a fragment and action bar drop down (spinner) and both will work independently.
thank you in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Acion bar Drop down with View Pager](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22496578/using-acion-bar-drop-down-with-view-pager)

Comment: So is it possible or not to use action bar drop down and view pager independently...if it is possible then please suggest me that way...or should i try another approach ... @adneal